# JQuery FadeOut not working correctly 1 way but is another

Tags: jquery, fade, fadeout

I have the following code here at

http://forum.castoff.net/menu.php

When i click the little x button it fades out correctly, but when i click the send button it just disappears without fade... even though it runs the same code..

HELP!!

Thanks in Advance

Lee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are submitting the form.

Add `return false;` to your submit trigger :) underneath all the post code!

Comment: Cool that seems to work... Why wasn't it working without that then ?

Comment: Because you are physically submitting the form which means the fadeOut function would come into effect after the page will refresh (ie. no visual fadeOut) so when you added return false it prevented the refresh of the page, hence the fadeOut was visual :)

Comment: what about submitting fading out first and sending the ajax request later?

Comment: My advice would be to use .ajax rather than .post, i would then put the fadeOut in the success callback of the .ajax function :)

Comment: I;ve never done ajax before.... I am posting to a PHP file that then will go on and get the correct email address from a user in the database and then send them the message in a email

Comment: ajax is very simple :) i wrote a tutorial about it on my blog: http://blog.twostepmedia.co.uk/send-html-form-results-in-an-email-from-php-using-jquery-ajax/ any problems, give me a shout on my site or on here!

Comment: doesn't fading first posting later help?

Comment: OK so what happens if the DIV fades out but then there is a problem with the ajax. If you do it on success callback you can notify the user right there and then